# multi-label classification error based on tf.slim

Tags: tensorflow

When build tfrecord, I have encoded the labels as N-hot encoding.

Then I comment the following code:

```
labels = slim.one_hot_encoding(
labels, dataset.num_classes - FLAGS.labels_offset)
```

But it crash when train:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../train_image_classifier_multilabel.py", line 620, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "../train_image_classifier_multilabel.py", line 519, in main
    clones = model_deploy.create_clones(deploy_config, clone_fn, [batch_queue])
  File "/root/Projects/scene-tf/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py", line 193, in create_clones
    outputs = model_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "../train_image_classifier_multilabel.py", line 513, in clone_fn
    label_smoothing=FLAGS.label_smoothing, weights=1.0)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/losses/losses_impl.py", line 676, in sigmoid_cross_entropy
    logits.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(multi_class_labels.get_shape())
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 764, in assert_is_compatible_with
    raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (32, 63) and (32,) are incompatible
```

The sigmoid_cross_entropy encounters problem:

```
tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(
logits=logits, multi_class_labels=labels,
label_smoothing=FLAGS.label_smoothing, weights=1.0)
```

Obviously, the shape of logits is   (32, 63)  and labels is  (32,) .

It seems that the comment of one_hot_encoding is wrong.
But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `logits` and `multi_class_labels` should both be of shape `[batch_size, num_classes]` ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/sigmoid_cross_entropy)). Can you post your full model?

Comment: I think the main problem is the lack of encoding function. Do anyone know how to  implement N-hot encoding which is aimed to replace one-hot encoding？

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599988/implement-n-hot-encoding-in-tf-slim/50600674)

Comment: Never mind I guess you were the one that asked it!