# implement N-hot encoding in tf.slim

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, encoding, one-hot-encoding

How to implement N-hot encoding according to the index of 1 in a tf.int64 ? The input is tensor containing several tf.int64. The N-hot encoding is aimed to replace one-hot encoding in tf.slim.

The one_hot encoding is implemented as following:

```
def dense_to_one_hot(labels_dense, num_classes):
  """Convert class labels from scalars to one-hot vectors."""
  num_labels = labels_dense.shape[0]
  index_offset = numpy.arange(num_labels) * num_classes
  labels_one_hot = numpy.zeros((num_labels, num_classes))
  labels_one_hot.flat[index_offset + labels_dense.ravel()] = 1
  return labels_one_hot
```

The N-not encoding means: 19=00010011, the result after encoding is [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1].

Comment: Is `N` always a constant value known at graph construction time or may it be the result of another TensorFlow operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one solution:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def n_hot_encoding(a, n):
    a = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
    m = 1 << np.arange(n)[::-1]
    shape = np.r_[np.ones(len(a.shape), dtype=int), -1]
    m = m.reshape(shape)
    hits = tf.bitwise.bitwise_and(a[..., tf.newaxis], tf.cast(m, a.dtype))
    return tf.not_equal(hits, 0)


with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    n_hot = n_hot_encoding([19, 20, 21], 10)
    print(sess.run(tf.cast(n_hot, tf.int32)))
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1]]
```

It assumes that the `N` is a regular scalar (not a TensorFlow value) and that the number of dimensions of the array to convert is known (the size of each dimension can be dynamic, but `a.shape` should not be just `None`). The function can be adapted to TensorFlow-only computation like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def n_hot_encoding(a, n):
    a = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
    n = tf.convert_to_tensor(n)
    m = tf.bitwise.left_shift(1, tf.range(n)[::-1])
    shape = tf.concat([tf.ones([tf.rank(a)], dtype=tf.int64), [-1]], axis=0)
    m = tf.reshape(m, shape)
    hits = tf.bitwise.bitwise_and(a[..., tf.newaxis], tf.cast(m, a.dtype))
    return tf.not_equal(hits, 0)
```

This should work with any input but may do a bit more of extra work on every graph run.

Comment: Great! But the output is bool. The output of slim.one_hot_encoding is tf.float32.

Comment: @T.Wang You can cast it, either inside or outside the function, with `tf.cast(n_hot, tf.float32)`.

Comment: isn't this one hot encoding @jdehesa? or n hot encoding happens to be when you define the length of your encoding like pre-defined 10 up there?

Comment: @Nihat One-hot encoding means e.g. converting `[1, 3, 2]` to `[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]]`. What OP wants here is essentially get every individual bit of each number, so `[1, 3, 2]` (in binary `[0b01, 0b11, 0b10]`) could be `[[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 0]]`.

Comment: @jdehesa That makes sense, thanks. But I see the usage of N hot encoding in the literature and could not find anything clearly. Could you enlighten me also on how would N hot encoding would occur in this situation? say 2 or 4 hot encodings?

Comment: @Nihat N-hot encoding may be useful for example in a multi-class classification problem. Let's say you want to recognise animals in pictures, each class being a species (cat, dog, etc.). You may consider the possibility that more than one species show up in a picture (e.g. a cat and a dog), and for those cases you may want to recognise _all_ of the species in the picture. An N-hot-encoded vector can represent that, with a `1` on every active class for the example. In that case you probably wouldn't use softmax output, but rather e.g. sigmoid activation (one separate "probability" per class).

Answer (score 2):

Find below an alternative to @jdehesa great answer. This version computes the bit length `N` itself (but works on single-valued tensors only - or tensors containing values of same bit length):

```python
import tensorflow as tf

def logn(x, n):
  numerator = tf.log(x)
  denominator = tf.log(tf.cast(n, dtype=numerator.dtype))
  return numerator / denominator

def count_bits(x):
    return tf.cast((logn(tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.float32), 2)) + 1, dtype=x.dtype)

def n_hot_encode(x):
    """
    Unpack an integer into its variable-length bit representation
    :param x: Int tensor of shape ()
    :return:  Bool tensor of shape (N,) with N = bit length of x
    """
    N = count_bits(x)
    bins = tf.bitwise.left_shift(1, tf.range(N))[::-1]
    x_unpacked = tf.reshape(tf.bitwise.bitwise_and(x, bins), [-1])
    x_bits = tf.cast(x_unpacked, dtype=tf.bool)
    return x_bits

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(n_hot_encode(tf.constant(19)))
    print(result)
    # > [ True False False  True  True]
    result = sess.run(n_hot_encode(tf.constant(255)))
    print(result)
    # > [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
```

---

#### Previous Answer:

Using [`tf.one_hot()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot):

```
labels_one_hot = tf.one_hot(labels_dense, num_classes)
```

Comment: tf.one_hot only  encodes one hot. It's not my meaning.

Comment: Ok, I may have got confused. I assumed you wanted to convert your numpy code into TF. Could you clarify in your question what you mean by "N-hot encoding" (e.g. with pseudo-code or numpy)?

Comment: For example, 19=00010011, the result after encoding is [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1]

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative to @jdehesa's answer (depending on your use-cases)